# How I Can Run Some Part of the Code on another EC2 instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg

I have a NodeJS application running on an **EC2 instance**, which has some feature where users can record multiple videos.

When the user logs out I am using [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg)(version **4.2.4**) to combine all those videos into single a video.

I am recording the video in `WEBM` format, and the final single video should be in `MP4` format.

Suppose the user has recorded 3 videos of 10 minutes each, then in last when the user logs out, all these 3 videos should be combined into the single video on length of 30 minutes.

Now everything is working fine, but the CPU usage is high when all the conversation and concatenation are going around.

CPU usage is sometimes as high as `60-70%`

The process I am following is

1. Convert the `webm` file to the `mp4` file.

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input_file.webm -c:v copy -c:a copy output_file.mp4
   ```
2. Convert MP4 to ts(Transport Stream) file.

   ```
    ffmpeg -i output_file.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts OUTPUT_MP4.ts
   ```

   I am following this process to concatenate all the mp4 files into one.
3. Concatenate files

   ```
   ffmpeg -i "concat:OUTPUT_MP4_1.ts|OUTPUT_MP4_2.ts|OUTPUT_MP4_3.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc FINAL_MP4_SINGLE_FILE.mp4
   ```

All this process is time-consuming(but not a priority), however, this process is taking CPU usage a lot.

The server can crash or become slow if there are many users on my application and may video conversion is going on.

Now, my question is how I can run this conversion process on the **dedicated** `EC2 instance` where only conversions can happen and not any other work, from the same code that is running on the first EC2 instance.

Comment: AWS sells an [elastic transcoding](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/) service which may do what you want. It has a queuing-based API.

Comment: @O.Jones Thanks for the quick response, but the thing is the user can have video as long as the user wanted, the [elastic transcoding](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder) can be quite expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a work queue of postprocessing tasks. A simple Javascript array can serve as a queue: you `.push()` new items into the queue and `.shift()` them out to consume them.

You will need a looping function to consume the queue, looking something like this.

```js
async function convertVideo (queue, completed) {
  while (true) {
    if (queue.length === 0) {
      await sleep(1000)
      continue
    }
    const item = queue.shift()
    await convertItem(item)
    completed.add(item)
  }
}
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

This function will run your `convertItem()` function on one item at a time. Invoke this function, just once, as your program starts up. Give it the queue.
I have thrown in a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to hold the completed items.

```js
const queue = []
const completed = new Set()
convertVideo(queue, completed).next()
```

You may want to deal with completion a different way.

This doesn't run the conversion on a different vitual machine. But it does keep your single instance from being overloaded.

You can add capacity in these ways:

- add cores to your VM, and run the convertVideo function twice to get two concurrent conversion operations.
- add new VMs with the same server software and load balance incoming requests.

If you *must* run the conversion on different VM, you need some sort of inter-VM queuing scheme so your web server machines can pass the work items to the conversion machines.  [Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/), [redis](https://redis.io/commands/RPOPLPUSH), and [RabbitMQ](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/how-to-run-rabbitmq-with-nodejs.html) are possible choices of inter-VM queueing technology. There are others.  It's hard to give detailed suggestions without knowing a lot more about the way your app works.

If you use separate VMs for processing, you'll find that the AWS elastic transcoding service has worked out all the operational details around queueing. It's expensive, but so is operating multicore EC2 instances 24x7.

Comment: I just have a doubt now, how do I move this process to another EC2 instance? What I mean is that suppose when the user press logs out, I run this above code you said, and this is present in my first EC2, I want that all the conversion should happen on the second EC2 instance, as mentioned in the question first EC2 instance will not be able to handle the load.

Comment: Thanks, I will try these options, let me see which works for me the best.

Comment: I tried the method to gave and implemented a queue for the postprocessing task.